# Set Cookie for UIWebView requests

Tags: uiwebview, xamarin.ios, nshttpcookie

I want to embed an `UIWebView` into my MonoTouch application for an area that is not yet implemented natively.

In order to authenticate with the website I want to set a cookie containing a key for the current session.

I tried creating a `NSDictionary` with the properties for the Cookie and then create a new `NSHttpCookie` and add it to the `NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage`.

Sadly the cookie seems to be empty and not used for the request.

An example of how to build be cookie with properties and a comment on whether or not this is the simplest way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I need to send cookies and params up to the server I use something like RestSharp or Hammock and then pass the response.Content value into UIWebView's loadHtmlString method:

```
//setup cookies and params here
var response = client.Execute(req);
_webView = new UIWebView();
_webView.LoadHtmlString(response.Content, new NSUrl(baseUrl));
```

The NSDictionary API is fairly trivial too:

```
var props = new NSMutableDictionary ();
props.Add (NSHttpCookie.KeyOriginURL, new
NSString("http://yodawg.com"));
props.Add (NSHttpCookie.KeyName, new NSString("iherd"));
props.Add (NSHttpCookie.KeyValue, new NSString("ulikecookies"));
props.Add (NSHttpCookie.KeyPath, new NSString("/"));
```

Comment: This throws an `ArgumentNullException` when adding the cookie to the storage, because the cookie returned with your code is null.

Comment: It seems I found a bug on the NSHttpCookie binding! I filed it. I'm also updating the answer with a workaround.

Comment: Thanks, I will have an eye on the [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3603) and try your solution.

Comment: Ok, I tried yours, and the cookie gets created as expected. I am using `localhost` as OriginURL (and some reverse proxy to inspect the requests), but the server never receives the cookie. So I looked at `NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.Cookies` and it just contains two cookies from Google, nothing more. Any ideas?

Comment: So, I had to use `http://` in the OriginURL and set the path, otherwise it wouldn't be added to the cookie storage.

Comment: Yep, updated code to reflect working path. Now you see why it's so much easier to use RestSharp to do the request? ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Following Anuj's [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3603) I felt bad about how many lines of code were required to create the cookies. So the next MonoTouch versions will have new constructors for `NSHttpCookie`, similar to [`System.Net.Cookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kbtshb1.aspx) that will allow you do to something like:

```
// this ctor requires all mandatory parameters 
// so you don't have to guess them while coding
var cookie = new NSHttpCookie ("iherd", "ulikecookies", "/", "yodawg.com");
```

You'll even be able to create a `NSHttpCookie` from a .NET `System.Net.Cookie`.

Note: Never hesitate to fill a bug report when an API proves to be way more complicated than it should be :-)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK every application has its own cookie storage so try to use this code before rendering the page in the UIWebView

```
        NSHttpCookie cookie = new NSHttpCookie()
        {
            Domain = "yourdomain.com",
            Name = "YourName",
            Value = "YourValue" //and any other info you need to set
        };
        NSHttpCookieStorage cookiejar = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;
        cookiejar.SetCookie(cookie);
```

I'm not in a MAC right now so im not able to test it hope this helps

---

okay sorry, i wasn't able to test it before posting, anyways I won't get home until tonight so give this a spin

```
var objects = new object[] { "http://yoururl.com", "CookieName", "CookieValue", "/" };
var keys = new object[] { "NSHTTPCookieOriginURL", "NSHTTPCookieName", "NSHTTPCookieValue", "NSHTTPCookiePath" };
NSDictionary properties = (NSDictionary) NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(objects, keys);
NSHttpCookie cookie = NSHttpCookie.CookieFromProperties(properties);
NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.SetCookie(cookie);
```

As you stated above, in the case that doesn't work might be a bug on monotouch binding so you can bind it manually by doing this

```
var objects = new object[] { "http://yoururl.com", "CookieName", "CookieValue", "/" };
var keys = new object[] { "NSHTTPCookieOriginURL", "NSHTTPCookieName", "NSHTTPCookieValue", "NSHTTPCookiePath" };
NSDictionary properties = (NSDictionary) NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(objects, keys);
NSHttpCookie cookie = (NSHttpCookie) Runtime.GetNSObject(Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr(new Class("NSHTTPCookie").Handle, new Selector("cookieWithProperties:").Handle, properties.Handle))
NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage.SetCookie(cookie);
```

also don't forget to include `using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;` if manually binding it

if manually binding works please don't forget to post a bug report on https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Alex

Comment: Sadly `Domain`, `Name` and `Value` properties are readonly, so I cannot make use of a high-level `NSHttpCookie` API. That's why I fiddled with `NSDictionary` but haven't figured out the internals yet, how to set the properties for a new cookie.

Comment: Many good hints in your post: I needed to prefix the OriginURL with `http://` and also set the path to `/`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I’ve wrote the NSMutableURLRequest+XSURLRequest catagory and XSCookie class to do this;-) http://blog.peakji.com/cocoansurlrequest-with-cookies/

Comment: Sorry, but this is about MonoTouch. The general concept on how to use cookies was clear, but the implementation apparently had some problems.

Answer (score 0):

This might give you a lead. Previously I used a similar strategy to make a

WebRequest to a site and collect cookies which were stored in the .Net/Mono CookieStore. Then when loading a url in the UIWebView I copied those cookies over to the NSHttpCookieStorage.

```
public NSHttpCookieStorage _cookieStorage; 

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the .NET cookie storage to the iOS NSHttpCookieStorage with Login Cookies
    /// </summary>
    void DotNetCookieStoreToNSHttpCookieStore()
    {
        foreach (Cookie c in _cookies.GetCookies(new Uri(UrlCollection["Login"], UriKind.Absolute))) {
            Console.WriteLine (c);
            _cookieStorage.SetCookie(new NSHttpCookie(c));
        }
    }
```