# Open SharePoint URL in UIWebView - Embedding credential into URL request to avoid prompt for credentials

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.mac

How I can Open SharePoint URL in UIWebView - Embedding credential into URL request to avoid prompt for credential. I am developing small application which can open specified SharePoint site URL without manually passing require credential. The URL I am trying to open needs credential but I want to embed these credential to the request I will make to open the URL ins UIWebView control. I don't want to open the URL in Safari.

In Simple words. I need to authenticate in the background. The user should navigate directly into the Sharepoint list page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the credentials on hands and the form authentication implementation, you could

1. login using `HttpClient` on behalf of the user
2. extract the cookie from `HttpResponseMessage`
3. set the cookie to `NSHttpCookieStorage`

Comment: How I can set the Cookie into UIWebView NSHttpCookieStorage

Comment: To set cookie, you may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/9417016/4599907 **(Note: The accepted answer there is outdated. Look at the answer posted by @poupou)**