# Adding cookies on loading a url on web view

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am creating an iOS app using Xamarin.

I am loading a url on a web view. This url is hosted on a secure server which needs to be authenticated.

I store cookies from login service of the app and want to set these cookies when loading  the web view. But I cannot get any method to add it.

Could any one help regarding this?

Loading url is done by this line `webview.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(urlq));`
But I can't add the cookies.

Comment: Could you show the code where you load and store the cookie?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Cookie for UIWebView requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396718/set-cookie-for-uiwebview-requests)

Comment: @angak As i try set cookies in HttpWebRequest ? Because i didn't get any method to set cookies in loading url.

Answer (score 0):

This might give you a lead. Previously I used a similar strategy to make a

WebRequest to a site and collect cookies which were stored in the .Net/Mono CookieStore. Then when loading a url in the UIWebView I copied those cookies over to the NSHttpCookieStorage.

```
public NSHttpCookieStorage _cookieStorage; 

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the .NET cookie storage to the iOS NSHttpCookieStorage with Login Cookies
    /// </summary>
    void DotNetCookieStoreToNSHttpCookieStore()
    {
        foreach (Cookie c in _cookies.GetCookies(new Uri(UrlCollection["Login"], UriKind.Absolute))) {
            Console.WriteLine (c);
            _cookieStorage.SetCookie(new NSHttpCookie(c));
        }
    }
```